# Running a Wine application from other user in openSUSE

Tags: x11, wine

```
diuban@linux-gnwf:~> gnomesu -u diub wine /home/diub/ed.exe
wine: cannot find L"Z:\\home\\diub\\ed.exe"
diuban@linux-gnwf:~> No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
```

How to get X server running so that is OK?

openSUSE 12.3
Gnome 3.6

Comment: I think the first bit shows that user diub does not have drive mappings set up properly. Then you seem to be running `No protocol specified`, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think the bit in the error message is the clue as to how to resolve this:

> Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
>   err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window

You're running this `wine` application as another user that doesn't have access and/or permissions to open GUI windows on user **diuban's** desktop. To resolve this you need to do 2 things.

1. $DISPLAY

   Confirm that the `$DISPLAY` environment variable is set.

   ```
   $ gnomesu -u diub echo $DISPLAY
   ```

   Assuming that it's set to **:0.0** or **:0** should be sufficient.
2. xhost

   To allow other users access to invoke GUI windows on your desktop you need to allow them permissions to do so. You can do a `xhost +` which will allow everyone permissions to do this, as use **diuban**.

   ```
   $ xhost +
   ```